# Draw lattice for a join-semillatice

Tags: discrete-mathematics, lattice-orders

I am working with a set that I believe is a join-semilattice (all elements $x,y\in S$ have a least upper bound). I am a little bit confused as to how I would draw a lattice for this set $S=\{1,2,3,12,18,36\}$ when it is partially ordered by divisibility.

My confusion stems from how I would draw the $12$ and $18$ in the lattice. Initially, I would draw a $1$ as the base. To the NW of $1$, I would draw a $2$ with a line going from $1$ to $2$. I would do the same for $1$ and $3$, except I would put the $3$ to the NE of $1$. This is just where I get a tiny bit confused. $2$ and $3$ divide both $12$ and $18$, but $12$ doesn't divide $18$. How would I make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this rough sketch:

[image]

Note that $2$ and $3$ do **not** have a least upper bound, since $12$ and $18$ are unrelated.

Comment: So is this set not a join-semilattice then?

Comment: @Tesla: That’s correct: it’s not. And since it looks the same when you flip it over, it’s also not a meet-semilattice.